# How to make Github sort the repository in numerical order?

Tags: git, github, repository, numerical

I had a question regarding Github's ordering of repository entries.
My repository looks like this:

[image]

If you notice, "ch2" should come after "ch1," and 10 11 should go at the end. I've read that Github currently doesn't support numerical ordering, and that there are "tricks" such as adding spaces at the end, but that doesn't seem to work.

I was wondering does anybody either know a trick or solution for this inconvenience?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**But this order is lexicographical**
(or better ASCIIbetical)

I would recommend to rename the chapters with fixed number width, such as `ch01`.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant "numeric," but thanks for the answer. I'll try that.